# Fargate Service discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, service-discovery, aws-fargate

I have issues in Fargate with service discovery.

Starting from this template: https://github.com/pjlewisuk/fargate-refarch-cloudformation, I added a "private" service reachable only from other containers. I enabled service discovery on the private service.

Everything looks fine: the namespace is added in Routed 53 and I can see my discovery service with an instance registered in CloudMap.

Nonetheless, when I try to reach that private task from another one via (http://servicename.namespace), I always get 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND'.

Anyone has any idea how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: trying to reach private container mean ? using nay url or you want to go inside that container ? using -it iterative tag of docker and k8s ???

Comment: I edited my question. I mean reaching with a http request. In my case I use axios in node.js. In Fargate I cannot "enter" in the task like k8s or docker.

Comment: sorry i forget about that in fargate we can not access under lying resources and cannot not execute commands

Comment: try adding this to ecs service "{ 
    ...
    "serviceRegistries": [
       {
          "registryArn": "arn:aws:servicediscovery:region:aws_account_id:service/srv-utcrh6wavdkggqtk"
       }
    ]
}"

Answer (score 5):

Did you enable the following properties in your VPC ?

"enableDnsHostnames": true
"enableDnsSupport" : true

[VPC DNS article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-updating)

Comment: You also need to associate your VPC with private zone in Route 53